# Imbrication promises to upload files angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, promise

I'm stuck for hours to upload an files array to my server. I need to upload this array and then upload an object using this files array as params. My server sends me back the uploaded file's name on the server side as response.  I'm confuse with the promise uses, because I obtain the error  :

```
 Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
```

Here is my code :

```
function uploadImage(formData){

 var deferred = $q.defer();
 Image.aadd(formData).then(function(data){
    deferred.resolve(data.data.fileName);
    return deferred.promise;
  });

 }

function uploadImages(gallery){

var myGallery = [];
angular.forEach(gallery, function (image) {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', image);

    var promise = uploadImage(formData);
    promise.then(function(data){
        myGallery.push(data.fileName);
    });

});

var mygallery = uploadImages($scope.stock.gallery);

// Then use mygallery ["imgName1.png","imgName2.jpg", ... ]
```

Comment: Which line that error is related?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`uploadImage()` should return a promise in order to have a `then()` function. Also, you can simplify your promise returning directly a value.

> When you return a value inside `then()`, this value will be passed to the first chained promise.

```
function uploadImage(formData) {
    return Image.add(formData).then(function(data) {
        return data.data.fileName;
    });
}
```

Then, you should reorganize your `uploadImages()` function. I suggest the following way.

```
function uploadImages(gallery) {
    var uploadPromises = gallery.map(function(image) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', image);
        return uploadImage(formData);
    });

    return Promise.all(uploadPromises);
}

uploadImages($scope.stock.gallery).then(function(mygallery) {
    // then you should use mygallery
});
```

**Explanation:** You should put all your upload promises into an array. Using `Promise.all` you can catch the moment when all your uploads are done. Then, you make an array with all filenames available through `then()`.

Comment: Thank you both for your answer and your explanation @Richard, works perfectly !